# How do I report a Wilcoxon-signed rank test if the medians are the same?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have data comparing 2 likert-scale answers (1 to 7) where the p<0.05 but the medians are the same.

I'm trying to report this in a table. My instinct was to report this similar to a t-test, with median, IQR, Z and effect size, but this way of reporting data does not work when the medians for the two items are the same.

Should I instead report on mean ranks? I feel this may make the data less readable to anyone who is not familiar with the wilxocon test.

If I were to take the route of just adding a footnote to any case where the medians are the same, what would be the best way to do that?